# Запуск и компиляция C++ кода из C# на лету

Tags: c#, c++

Краткая история: пишу диплом. Оптимизация с++ кода. Переделываю блок switch в массив.
Чуть больше подробностей: Пишу на C# с WinForms. Тобишь, весь парсинг и прочая работа делается на C#.

Задача: после того, как я оптимизировал всё, мне требуется запустить новый, сформированный .cpp файл, откомпилировать его, и запустить. И встает самый глубокий и сложный для меня вопрос, как это сделать из c# когда?

Можно предположить, что это можно сделать средствами командной строки(из кода, к примеру, вначале порождать дочерний процесс, который откомпилирует файл, и потом передать его на вход дочернему процессу, который его запустит). Ну и соответственно, результатом выполнения будет возврат четырех DWORD чисел, содержащих в себе результаты GetTIckCount() для замера скорости работы до и после(2 до оптимизация и 2 после).

Что посоветуете?

p.s. если вдруг такая магия запрещена, то может быть это можно сделать при помощи Node.js, уж он то точно умеет порождать дочерние процессы через консоль, с указанными параметрами. Но проблема в его запусте та же, запуск его как дочерний процесс.
p.s.s.

```
Превращаю это:  
switch (i % 30) {
      case 15: res = 30; break;
      ...
      case 26: res = 50; break;
      case 27: res = 57; break;
      case 28: res = 70; break;
      default: res = 0;
    }  

Вот в это:  

static int k[30] = { 30,45,0,0,0,0,50,57,70,80,81,50,57,70 };
    res = k[(i % 30) - 15];
```

Comment: А вы уверены, что ваша оптимизация - это оптимизация? Вы замеры производительности делали? Что то я сомневаюсь, что данная тема достойна диплома

Comment: _это можно сделать средствами командной строки(из кода, к примеру, вначале порождать дочерний процесс, который откомпилирует файл, и потом передать его на вход дочернему процессу, который его запустит)_

Comment: Компилятор умнее такого класса оптимизаций, примите как должное. Лучше включить принудительно векторизацию в компиляторе, толку будет больше.

Comment: В чем именно трудность? В выборе компилятора С++, выборе параметров компиляции для вашей программы, в запуске его из C# или в измерении времени работы?

Comment: Темы не для обсуждения, хорошая эта оптимизация, или какова.  
Был поставлен вопрос, на счет компиляции и запуска с++ кода из c#, давайте придерживаться этой линии.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, трудность в компиляци с++ кода при помощи средств c# и его последующий запуск, с выводом потока данных обратно

Comment: Это довольно обширная тема. Как минимум, вам нужно выбрать между использованием системы сборки (msbuild/cmake) или прямым вызовом компилятора и компоновщика. Если вы вообще не понимаете, что это все значит, начните с этого раздела документации: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/projects-and-build-systems-cpp?view=vs-2017 По запуску процессов из C#, опять же, см. документацию: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight, т.е. фактически возможно из c# (инфа по ссылке 2) запускать *.bat файл, в котором прописаны все инструкции для msbuild по компиляции и запуску .cpp файла. А выходную информацию передавать, к примеру. через файл?

Comment: Да, можно и так. Можно и не через файл, а использовать RedirectStandardOutput и считывать вывод в самой программе.